# Entity Framework L2 Caching with AppFabric: Am I doing it right?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, caching, appfabric

I have successfully employed the EF Provider wrappers to do "L2" caching:
https://efwrappers.codeplex.com/

The design supports multiple "cache providers" (in-memory, asp.net cache). Now I need to bring this to a cluster, with shared cache. I found an article from Julie Lerman showing how to use AppFabric as a cache provider:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh394143.aspx

The code comes from an MSDN article, but it seems to be a broken design. I am not an expert with AppFabric but I see 3 issues, one of which is fundamentally incorrect use of the cache api. Is anyone else using an AppFabric caching provider? Does anyone else see issues in the code example supplied by Julie?

```
//This class was based on the VelocityCacheAdapter clas
//MSDN Magazine Sept 2011 Data Points Column Sample Code
//(Julie Lerman)
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using EFCachingProvider.Caching;
using Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching;

namespace EFAppFabricCacheAdapter
{

  public class AppFabricCache : ICache
  {
    private DataCache _cache;

    public AppFabricCache(DataCache cache)
    {
      _cache = cache;
    }

    public bool GetItem(string key, out object value)
    {
      key = GetCacheKey(key);
      value = _cache.Get(key);

      return value != null;
    }

    //!!!ISSUE #1: Minor issue: No try/catch around the call to _cache.Put. 
    // The event that separate workers try to update the same entry will cause
    // exceptions. 
    //!!!ISSUE #2: The query is cached without a region. 
    // The dependent sets are cached in regions. 
    //This works well when you are invalidating a specific item but 
    //it fails when you invalidate sets, all related items to the set are not removed

    public void PutItem(string key, object value,
      IEnumerable<string> dependentEntitySets, 
      TimeSpan slidingExpiration, DateTime absoluteExpiration)
    {
      key = GetCacheKey(key);
      _cache.Put(key, value, absoluteExpiration - DateTime.Now, 
        dependentEntitySets.Select(c => new DataCacheTag(c)).ToList());

      foreach (var dep in dependentEntitySets)
      {
        CreateRegionIfNeeded(dep);
        _cache.Put(key, " ", dep);
      }

    }

//!!!ISSUE #2 again: say i have a customer and orders. 
//If I invalidate the order set then any related customer/order 
//query should be removed. This just clears regions but doesnt remove the actual
//queries. This design will leave stale objects in cache
//!!!ISSUE #3: minor issue, but calling _cache.GetObjectsInRegion and iterating will 
// cause unnecessary I/O. Changing this to calling region.Clear() will 
// be more efficient.
    public void InvalidateSets(IEnumerable<string> entitySets)
    {
      // Go through the list of objects in each of the set. 
      foreach (var dep in entitySets)
      {
        foreach (var val in _cache.GetObjectsInRegion(dep))
        {
          _cache.Remove(val.Key);
        }
      }
    }

    public void InvalidateItem(string key)
    {
      key = GetCacheKey(key);

      DataCacheItem item = _cache.GetCacheItem(key);
      _cache.Remove(key);

      foreach (var tag in item.Tags)
      {
        _cache.Remove(key, tag.ToString());
      }
    }

    //creates a hash of the query to store as the key  
    private static string GetCacheKey(string query)
    {
      byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(query);
      string hashString = Convert
        .ToBase64String(MD5.Create().ComputeHash(bytes));
      return hashString;
    }

    private void CreateRegionIfNeeded(string regionName)
    {
      try
      {
        _cache.CreateRegion(regionName);
      }
      catch (DataCacheException de)
      {
        if (de.ErrorCode != DataCacheErrorCode.RegionAlreadyExists)
        {
          throw;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```